# How to find a negative value for cosine function?

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone explain me how to find a negative value of a cosine function like how to find x if $$\cos x=-\sqrt3/2$$
I just don't understand how to do it? Please explain it to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solve $\cos x=\frac{\sqrt 3}2$ and recall that $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$.

Comment: oh yeah yeah i got it thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I always do this kind of problem from this drawing of the trigonometric circle:

[image]